# Remove all files except the largest

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder with many sub-folders. I want to remove all smaller files from each subfolder, only leaving the biggest file.

For example:

```
Subfolder1
---------- File 1 ---- 300k
---------- File 2 ---- 299k
---------- File 3 ---- 800k
```

Only `file 3` should remain the with 800k.
If the folder only has one file, it remains.

This code works, but i can't put it in a for loop (for directory recursive):

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | sort -n -r | tail -n +2 | xargs -I{} rm -v {}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This command works, but i can't put it in for loop, doesnt works:
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | sort -n -r | tail -n +2 | xargs -I{} rm -v {}

Comment: What should the algorithm do when you got a "folder" containing <800k files only?

Comment: 800k is a example, the script should delete all files except the largest for folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~$ tree -fQFi --sort=size pluto
"pluto"
"pluto/pluto1"/
"pluto/pluto1/pluto3"/
"pluto/pluto1/pluto3/nozero.txt"
"pluto/pluto1/pluto3/zero ed.txt"
"pluto/pluto1/nozero.txt"
"pluto/pluto2"/
"pluto/pluto2/nozero.txt"
"pluto/pluto2/nozer.txt"
"pluto/pluto2/zero.txt"
"pluto/pluto4"/
"pluto/pluto4/zeroed.txt"
"pluto/zeroed.txt"

4 directories, 8 files

~$ tree -fQFic --noreport --sort=size pluto | \
> awk -F"/" 'NR==1||/\/$/{next}; \
>     {path=""; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) path=path$i; if(a[path]++) print}'
"pluto/pluto1/pluto3/zero ed.txt"
"pluto/pluto2/nozer.txt"
"pluto/pluto2/zero.txt"

~$ tree -fQFic --noreport --sort=size pluto | \
> awk -F"/" 'NR==1||/\/$/{next}; \
>     {path=""; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) path=path$i; if(a[path]++) print}' | \
> xargs rm -v
'pluto/pluto1/pluto3/zero ed.txt' rimosso
'pluto/pluto2/nozer.txt' rimosso
'pluto/pluto2/zero.txt' rimosso

~$ tree -fQFi --sort=size pluto
"pluto"
"pluto/pluto1"/
"pluto/pluto1/pluto3"/
"pluto/pluto1/pluto3/nozero.txt"
"pluto/pluto1/nozero.txt"
"pluto/pluto2"/
"pluto/pluto2/nozero.txt"
"pluto/pluto4"/
"pluto/pluto4/zeroed.txt"
"pluto/zeroed.txt"

4 directories, 5 files
```

`tree` lists by directory, and then by descending size.

- `awk`'s 1st line of code skips `tree`'s output 1st line **or** lines with trailing slashes (i.e. directories)
- `awk`'s 2st line of code builds a dirname from full path (`for` loop), then prints full path names iff dirname was encountered once on previous lines (i.e. it prints, for each directory, from 2nd listed file on)

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/108618).

Comment: Could you please be more verbose? I quickly read that link, is your idea that `ls` outputs shouldn't be fed to other commands?

Comment: It shouldn't. There's a link in the very first sentence of the question I linked to; its target is better than my verbose comment, whatever it would be.

Comment: Edited, I am following your advice Kamil. Meta: pointing directly to the link you were referring to would have saved both your time and mine.

Comment: That link is external, the site may disappear. Therefore I chose to point to SE question where the subject is covered.

Comment: I'm glad you took my advice, not everyone would bother. Unfortunately you seem to have missed my point, as `tree` also shouldn't be parsed for similar reasons. I don't want to make you edit the answer again; I just want you to know the limitations of the tools we use. In an empty directory perform a test: `touch "$(echo -ne "foo\nbar")"`, then `ls | xargs stat`, then `tree -fQFic --noreport  | xargs stat`, then `find | xargs stat`, then `echo * | xargs stat`, then `find -exec stat {} \;`, then `find -print0 | xargs -0 stat`, then `stat *` and you will know which tool can be parsed and how.

Comment: I appreciate your heads up on my solution, not being 100% general, although I doubt many users put line breaks into their file names. Do you think there is a safe, efficient way to achieve what the OP is asking for?

Comment: You need to parse all paths and filenames as null-terminated strings and abandon tools that replace some characters with others (like `ls`). `find` is good, usually with `-print0` or `-exec`. Every tool that deals with names should support this mode: `exec -0`, `sort -z` etc. [One of my answers](https://superuser.com/a/1224295/432690) uses this approach to find a recently modified directory. Adjust `stat` to make it work with sizes. You'll need to work in every directory separately so there should be an outer `find` that travels through directories. You're right, it may be an overkill.

Comment: "Do you think there is a safe, efficient way to achieve what the OP is asking for?" – I posted my own answer, I consider it safe (I may be wrong, still it's safer than `ls` or `tree` approach for sure). A Pearl or Python script would probably be more efficient, also I expect it (note: I'm not a programmer) to use null-terminated paths by default, while in `bash` you have to pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

#### Justification

This is my attempt to build a command that will work with *any* directory and file name(s). In general paths in Linux (and names in filesystems) may contain any character but null (`0x00`) and `/`. Troublesome characters may be "" (space), any other white character, `'`, `"`, newline, other non-printable characters. Therefore it's important to:

- abandon tools that replace some characters with others (e.g. many implementations of `ls` will print `?` for non-printables);
- pass all names as null-terminated strings (choose tools that can parse them);
- quote properly.

I was inspired by the discussion under [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1213622/432690).

---

#### Actual commands

Testing version, it will only `ls` files that would be removed:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec stat --printf "%s %n\0" \{\} + | sort -znr | tail -zn +2' {} \; | cut -zf 2- -d " " | xargs -0r ls -l
```

Yes, I'm using `ls` here in spite of what I've just said. This is because `ls` output is not being parsed further. I'm using it only to display the result. If you happen to have directories or files with troublesome characters in their names then you will observe the behavior of `ls` which should convince you to [never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (unless you know you're absolutely safe with it). Still the troublesome names will pass all the way to `ls` and this is the point.

**Understand the testing version** (see down below for some explanation) **and try it before you let the working version** (just below) **remove your files.** Remember I'm just a random guy on the Internet.

**Working version, it will remove your files:**

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec stat --printf "%s %n\0" \{\} + | sort -znr | tail -zn +2' {} \; | cut -zf 2- -d " " | xargs -0r rm
```

---

#### Explanation

Here's the testing version split into multiple lines (although it's still one line to `bash`; note I use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456019) to inline comments):

```
find -type d -exec   `# Find all directories under (and including) the current one.` \
  sh -c '            `# In every directory separately...` \
    find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec   `# ...find all files,...` \
      stat --printf "%s %n\0" \{\} + |   # ...get their sizes and names,...
    sort -znr |                          # ...sort by size...
    tail -zn +2'                        `# ...and discard the "biggest" entry.` \
    {} \
  \; |                                   # (All the directories have been processed).
cut -zf 2- -d " "  |                     # Then extract filenames...
xargs -0r ls -l                          # ...and ls them (rm in the working version).
```

Techniques used, obstacles overcome:

- Tools that parse strings are told to work with null-terminated strings:

  - `stat --printf "…\0"`;
  - `sort -z`, `tail -z`, `cut -z`;
  - `xargs -0 …`;
  - `find -print0` (not needed in this example but very common in general, therefore I mention it anyway).
- `sh -c '…'` is the way to use pipes inside `find -exec`.
- `find -type d -exec sh -c 'find "{}" …` will break for directory name containing `"`; `find -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" … ' {} \;` works fine.
- `{}` in the inner `find` statement are escaped (`\{\}`) to prevent the outer `find` substituting them.
- `cut` could immediately follow `tail`, it would run one `cut` per directory. Placing it outside the outer `find` makes a single `cut` do all the cutting at once.
- The `-r` option to `xargs` prevents `ls` (`rm` in the working version) from running when there's no input to `xargs`.