# How to delete all files in all subdirectories while keeping the biggest file in each subdirectory under Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, video, size

This is my first question, thank you for allowing me to ask and for reading my question!

I am under Ubuntu 22.04 w. GNOME Shell and the bash shell.
I have a folder with over 800 subdirectories.
Each subdirectory contains from 4 to up of 8 versions of the very same video in different resolutions.
For each video/subdirectory I want to keep only the best resolution.

How do I recursively delete all files in all subdirectories keeping only the biggest file in each subdirectory?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can start by doing something like the script here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47593062/7411885 (sorting by size instead of date), and looping through each folder

Comment: Are you sure the largest file is also the one with the best quality? – As there are more efficient codecs creating smaller sized results than other ones but with better results.

Comment: 2 I don't know exactly how to put it. But reading the answers I do come to realize that I wasn't following community rules and basic etiquette, and by that maybe even trying or effectively taking advantage of superuser.com members. I am very sorry for my conduct and very kindly ask for apologies. I could have avoided my acts by reading the rules and "How to ask" beforehand, I apologize for that too.

Comment: 1: Thank you very very much for your reply. Sadly, as I will try to explain further down, I lack the necessary skills to take advantage of it. It is my fault for not reading the rules, but your help is very very much appreciated.

Comment: 3: dodrg: You are right. I didn't think of it. I figured trying to figure out bitrates, resolutions and now even CODECs would have required more elaborate coding than just what the the filesystem very fastly offered. Going by byte size was a "quick and dirty" way of picking one the files fast. I figured the difference in quality wouldn't have been that big. Aside moreoiver as all files are from the same provider I sillily thought only one type CODEC would have been in use.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not going to write a script for you but here is one possible algorithm that could be used. (while the following uses scripting elements, it is far from being an accurate script and simply trying to plug in commands could be catastrophic)

**Before doing any of this, I strongly suggest copying the entire directory structure to another disk where you can test a script before executing it and accidently delete files you cannot recover**

1. From the top directory, `fldrLst='find ./ -type d'` (I'm using single quotes for left tick marks)
2. From the top directory, loop through `$fldrLst` while doing the following

   - Get a list of files from a single directory leaf in descending file size: `fileLst='find $fldrList[n] -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec ls -al {} \; | sort k 5 -nr'` where `[n]` is a specific member of the list array.
   - Count files in directory leaf: `echo $fildLst | wc -l`
   - Remove each file after the first entry (which should be the biggest file): loop through `$fileLst` and remove `rm $fileList[n]` (where the first `n` is the second entry in the array).

---

This should get you on the right track to accomplishing your task.

---

If this answer is useful in helping you arrive at your solution, please be sure to mark it as an answer or upvote it as a partial solution.

Comment: I bet the filenames contain spaces.

Comment: Actually they do (of course), yet somehow that didn0t prevet success.

Answer (score 0):

[linux - Remove all files except the largest - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1213492/remove-all-files-except-the-largest)

Testing version, it will only ls files that would be removed:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec stat --printf "%s %n\0" \{\} + | sort -znr | tail -zn +2' {} \; | cut -zf 2- -d " " | xargs -0r ls -l
```

Working version, it will remove your files:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec stat --printf "%s %n\0" \{\} + | sort -znr | tail -zn +2' {} \; | cut -zf 2- -d " " | xargs -0r rm
```

Original code by [Kamil Maciorowski](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski)

Comment: Hello, if you find a duplicate question that's answered, you should remove your question or report it as duplicate. Duplicatequestions are not quite welcome on this network.

Comment: I just tried to delete my question. But was frightened into not doing so as it said my account could be blocked beacuase of deleting questions with answers

Comment: I don't know, some of the mechanisms on this network are beyond stupid. But it got closed by someone (?) so no worries.

Comment: Actually deleted this question a second time yet nothing seems to happen. Will check again tomorrow.